# Declaration of constructor with multiple interfaces and inheritances

Tags: php, constructor

I have 2 interfaces and 2 classes in my example.

**Interfaces:**

```
interface I {
  public function __construct() { ... }
}

interface J {
  public function __construct($var1, $var2) { ... }
}

interface K {
  public function __construct($var) { ... }
}
```

**Classes**

```
class A implements I {
  public function __construct() { ... }
}

class B extends A implements J {

  public function __construct($var1, $var2) {
    parent::__construct();
    ...
  }
}

class C extends B implements K {

  public function __construct($var) {
    parent::__construct('var1', 'var2');
    ...
  }
}
```

As you can see, all classes build on each other. I also need the interfaces, because there are multiple 'types' of the classes `A`, `B` and `C`.

How can I achieve this, because the constructor on class `C` tells me the following error message:

> Declaration must be compatible with J->__construct($var1, $var2).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why did you add constructors to your interfaces? Does it really matter from that classes' users' perspective how many params should be passed into constructor?

Comment: Before I had this error, I thought it was cleaner in regards of my use case. But if the only solution to fixing this error is to remove the constructors in the interfaces, I'll do it.

Comment: If an interface defines a constructor, all implementing classes must use that constructor.  You can only override a constructor if it is not in the interface.  You can try to use a variadic constructor or `func_get_args` if you need multiple constructor signatures.

Comment: @Jan It's not the only way - it's the proper way. :) Again, interfaces allow to give your _objects_ - built with different classes - the same behaviour from their users' perspective. Adding constructors to interfaces means those users should somehow be responsible for instantiating those objects too.

Comment: I think you were looking for [class abstraction](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php) instead of class interfaces. Interfaces are intended to act as instructions or the requirement for implementation.